# React-Native Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

Tags: react-native, expo

я использую в своём проекте expo и когда я пытаюсь сбилдить проект я получаю ошибку на восьмидесяти процентах билда "Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED". Пробовал удалять папку android, переустанавливал модули, ничего не помогло.
Прикрепил примерный лог, когда процесс билда умирает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)